# Can we have multiple GET methods in a class, in a Jersey web app?

Tags: jakarta-ee, routes, jersey-2.0

I have the following code

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;

@Path("/")
public class HomeController {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/help")
    public Viewable help() {
        return new Viewable("/help");
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/")
    public Viewable index() {
        return new Viewable("/index");
    }
}
```

and the web.xml has the following mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mysite</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Invoking http://localhost:8080/mysite and http://localhost:8080/mysite/help, both requests route only to the index method. I have changed the servlet-* tags to filter-* tags, and also the url-pattern to /* as well. But nothing seems to work. I'm not able to route to any page other than the index. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the slashes on the methods:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;

@Path("/")
public class HomeController {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("help")
    public Viewable help() {
        return new Viewable("/help");
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable index() {
        return new Viewable("/index");
    }
}
```